# mdadm - how to unmount a kernel-mounted array?

Tags: raid, mdadm

This may sound like a silly question and the solution may be obvious but how do you unmount a kernel-mounted mdadm array? I've grown an array, something I've done many times over the years, and want to unmount it to resize the filesystem. What I've found using Ubuntu 16.04.3 (I previously had 12.04.latest and this didn't come up) is that I'm unable to unmount the array.

```
sudo umount /dev/md0  leads to 

umount: /media/RAID_video1: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

Fair enough, so I checked to see what PID was locking it:

```
sudo fuser -vm /dev/md0
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/md0:            root     kernel mount /media/RAID_video1
```

Since the array is still mounted I can't stop it either. Killing the kernel isn't an option so what am i missing? I've done this before many times using Ubuntu 12.04.latest and haven't seen this before so i assume it a new behaviour of 16.04.3 or the mdadm version it uses.

I'm sure I could edit my fstab or mdadm.conf files and reboot so the array isn't mounted in the first place but that doesn't sound like a very elegant solution. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I guess there was some other process active while you tried to `umount` the md raid array. It should work just fine and the `sudo fuser -vm /dev/md0` is expected to show kernel as the sole user if nobody else is using it. However, by the time you did run the `fuser` command there shouldn't have been any problem unmounting the volume.